# Input inside of a button in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have a UI that allows a user to change the text on a button. When they click an edit icon, it puts the button text into a text input where they can edit it, then save. Now, this works fine in Chrome, but doesn't work in IE11 nor Firefox, even when I stop the event from propagating. It seems like the event never makes it to the text input in IE11 and Firefox.

```
<button type='button'>
<input type='text' id='mybutton' />
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s0duxn5f/

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to make this work in IE11 and Firefox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is invalid in HTML. When you declare anything inside a button, it overwrites any other embedded control inside it. therefore, you cannot have access to those nested elements. If you are trying to focus on the input field on click of the button, you can do the following.

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    $('#mybutton').focus();
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/s0duxn5f/1/

To the original question, if you want to show the button text on click of the button to edit, you'll have to try some hack like the following :

```
 <button id="button" type='button'>Text
 </button>
 <script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(e) {
        if($(this).find('input').length == 0)
           $(this).append("<input type='text' id='mybutton'/>");    
        $('#mybutton').val($("#button").text());  
        $('#mybutton').focus();
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
      if(e.target.id != "")
         e.stopPropagation(); 
      else   
         $('#button').text($("#mybutton").val());     
    });
});
</script>
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/s0duxn5f/3/

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `<button>` to a `<span>`.

```
<span class='button'>
  <input type='text' id='mybutton' />
</span >
```

Then give the `<span>` CSS so it looks like and behaves like a button:

```
.button {
    cursor: pointer;
    // other css to make it look nice
}
```

Then add a `click` handler

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
    // handle button
});
$("#mybutton").click(function(e) {
    // handle input
});
```